# Dedupe Email in Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using Automation in Exacttarget to schedule and deploy a survey email to everyone who made a purchase yesterday. However, if a person has already been sent this email, I'd like to be able to suppress the person from receiving this survey email. Is there a way to do this in ET?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with an Exclusion Script in the Send Definition.  For example:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("EXCLUSION_DE", "SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey)) > 1
```

You can modify this AMPScript however you want as long as it evaluates as `True` or `False`.

The Exclusion Scripts have to be enabled by SFMC Support.

Comment: Sweet. Would you checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.  For more information about accepting answers, take a look at our [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).